# Which SQL Query is more efficient?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Which of the two queries is more efficient?

1. `SELECT *FROM Emp
   WHERE DeptNo<>20`
2. `SELECT *FROM Emp
   WHERE NOT Deptno=20`

My trainer told me the 1st one is more efficient and I understand the reason but how can I check this using Oracle 10g? He used some commands to show the CPU cycles consumed but I can't find them after a Google Search.

Outputs using AUTOTRACE are the same.

```
SQL> SELECT *FROM Emp
    WHERE DeptNo<>20

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0      SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer=ALL_ROWS (Cost=3 Card=9 Bytes=333
          )

   1    0   TABLE ACCESS (FULL) OF 'EMP' (TABLE) (Cost=3 Card=9 Bytes=
          333)
Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          1  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          8  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       1125  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        508  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          9  rows processed
```

```
SQL> SELECT *FROM Emp
WHERE NOT Deptno=20

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
   0      SELECT STATEMENT Optimizer=ALL_ROWS (Cost=3 Card=9 Bytes=333
          )

   1    0   TABLE ACCESS (FULL) OF 'EMP' (TABLE) (Cost=3 Card=9 Bytes=
          333)


Statistics
----------------------------------------------------------
          0  recursive calls
          0  db block gets
          8  consistent gets
          0  physical reads
          0  redo size
       1125  bytes sent via SQL*Net to client
        508  bytes received via SQL*Net from client
          2  SQL*Net roundtrips to/from client
          0  sorts (memory)
          0  sorts (disk)
          9  rows processed
```

Comment: I very much doubt that one of the queries is measurably faster than the other one.

Comment: in general, a lot depends on the statistics. this one though seems to be same for all .

Comment: Note how both had 8 consistent gets?  Neither is more efficient than the other.

Comment: Hmmm. You said the trainer gave you a reason? What was it? (allow us to poke fun at it....)

Comment: WHERE NOT Deptno=20 . first the SQL Engine will filter Deptno=20 and then it will apply the NOT operator , these are part of ANSI specs while deptno<>20 will produce the results in one scan . Now you can poke fun on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In oracle both of these will be processed in the same way. Any difference will occur in parsing (=subdividing) the query, and even that will be make know difference if the queries run several times, because the parsing results are cached.

Focus efficiency efforts on more inefficient processes, e.g. joins and subqueries.

Comment: is there any way i can check the CPU cycles ? There will 14scans for the 1st query and 28scans for the 2nd query?

Comment: The query is so simplistic that you won't see a difference. If you want to measure one regardless, CPU cycles vary with implementations. Try testing on large record numbers (tens of 1000s). But indexing the DEPTNO colmun has more effect than the exact way you write "NOT".

Answer (score 4):

From the statistics they both look equal.  A couple of tips though:

- Don't use `select *`, only select the fields you need
- Make sure you have indexes set up properly

Answer (score 1):

The AUTOTRACE is telling you that in this case, the queries have been executed the exact same way, and therefore neither is better than the other. Both involved a full table scan. Databases can be pretty smart about optimizing. It is possible that Oracle spent 1 nanosecond less deriving the query plan for the `<>` version.

The general point that your trainer *might* have been trying to make involves when an index can be used, and when not. So, a SELECT with IN is likely to run faster than a SELECT with a NOT IN, because the DB has a better chance of using an index search for the former.